# Can not Select and Add images for new properties in Wp Houzez theme

Tags: wordpress, media

Few days ago in our webpage we could no longer see and select images for the new properties we are adding.
[image]

Maybe somebody experianced something like that or knows how to fix it?

Comment: https://favethemes.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360041639432-Changelog In the last update says its fixed. Contact theme author if you face issues.

Comment: Thank you for the link!
I have found this on how to update.
https://favethemes.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360038091792-How-To-Update-Houzez
How can I do an update if I do not have the file of the Houzez theme? I had an agency do the website for me and then I decided to take care of the website on my own.

Comment: In the link i send says its updated so you should be able to update it if you have license ? Contact author for help.

Comment: The way I found to update is with a file of Houzez theme. I have the purchse code but I do not have the file with the theme. Is there a place I can download?

Comment: From where did you purchased this theme ? The official website sells it on themeforest so if you purchased from there login to your account and go to downloads and download the theme and upload it back on your server. Here you can find how to activate your theme so you can directly update it - https://favethemes.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360038091752-Theme-Activation or any other questions you have - https://favethemes.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/categories/360002468932-Houzez

Comment: We did not purchase it directly. As I was saying previously we had agency make a website for us and now we have cut all the ties with that agency and we have this issue where we can no longer add properties or update the theme.

Comment: Go to Themeforest and purchase a license. Then follow the steps to add the code in your theme settings and you will be able to update it with all plugins that come with the theme too. Also, not updating your WordPress to the latest version will lead to more problems in the future, so I recommend getting the license.

Comment: We have a purchase code in the theme. It is not possible to get updated version with that?
Wordpress theme we are going to update but next version and hopefully we will not experiance the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

The solution we went with as we do not have access to the houzez theme files was to downgrade the wordpress theme to 6.2.2 as the issue was by the wordpress update to 6.3

Here is some info of how to downgrade your wordpress version. We installed the WP Downgrade plugin and downgraded to 6.2.2. Everything seems to be functioning perfectly.
https://blogvault.net/downgrade-wordpress-to-previous-version-quickly/

Answer (score 0):

So @Tomas I have the perfect solution! I have updated the theme with very many technical issues that demanded FTP/Cpanel usage.

Need help then we need to be in touch

[view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ecexM.png)

[view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVGxI.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on one of my sites. I have 2 sites that run Houzez and both on Wordpress 6.3. But on one the media upload was fine. The problem(fix).. was that the one not showing the media upload needed one of the Houzez required plugins to be updated. Fixed!

Comment: which plugin do you use friend?
I have the same problem